# Obtain the "absolute path to the workbook" from an .xls file

Tags: vba, excel, apache-poi

When I use the Excel "Document Inspector" on a particular .xls file to check for "hidden properties or personal information" it says:

> The following document information was found:
>   * Absolute path to the workbook

How can I obtain the absolute path of the workbook from the file?  If it needs to be done programmatically, I could use Java (e.g. Apache POI) or VBA.

I know where the file is currently saved, but what I want to extract is the absolute path to the workbook which is saved in the file I have.  This is so I can know where it was saved by the author.

Here's what has happened to the file:

1. Someone authored it, saving it at some absolute filepath unknown to me
2. They uploaded it to a website
3. I downloaded it from the website

Excel indicates that the document contains the absolute path from step 1.  I'm after this path, not the place I saved it at step 3 since I know that.

Comment: perhaps `=CELL("filename")` works for you?

Comment: @CallumDA This returns the current spreadsheet location and workbook name.

Comment: What's the difference then? I'm not sure what you're looking for. Doesn't `=Cell("filename")` return something like `C:\Users\Myself\blah\[VariousData.xlsx]SummarySheet`? What's the "abosulte path" you're looking for?

Comment: @BruceWayne I've some steps to the question in an attempt to clarify.  I want to know the absolute path to the document which is saved in the spreadsheet itself, rather than where it is now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I can reproduced that warning message by simply creating an empty Excel file, added a formula, saved it as BIFF8 (.xls). The Document Inspector will then warn about the absolute path. ... but in my case, there was no filename inside the file.

A simple way to verify this, is to open the file in a hex-editor and search for a well-known save location (i.e. the location where a dummy/test file was stored)  - this is either stored as ASCII or as 16-bit string, i.e. every odd byte is a character.

If you want to use the POI developer tools, you can use the following:

To list all Excel records:
`java -cp poi-3.16-beta1.jar org.apache.poi.hssf.dev.BiffViewer file.xls`

To list the document and summary properties:
`java -cp poi-3.16-beta1.jar org.apache.poi.hpsf.extractor.HPSFPropertiesExtractor file.xls`

To list any embedded objects beside the usual suspects `SummaryInformation`, `DocumentSummaryInformation` and `Workbook`:
`java -cp poi-3.16-beta1.jar org.apache.poi.poifs.dev.POIFSLister file.xls`

So after running the tools and recording the output, you can then remove the properties via the Excel Document Inspector and execute the tools again. The output can be diffed and you might find the culprit.

Comment: I tried a hex editor on the file I have and found nothing before posting this question.  I thought perhaps Excel used some esoteric encoding.  I've ran the commands you listed, which all worked but none produced the full path.  So potentially it's being reported incorrectly by Excel in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

Assuming it is an `.xlsx` file rather than an older-style `.xls` file, you can

1. Rename the workbook as a `.zip` file
2. Look at the `xl\workbook.xml` "file" within the `.zip` file

and you will find the absolute path when last saved from Excel.

This is why it is not a good idea to share work-related spreadsheets with other people, unless you first clear out this sort of information.

---

I'm not sure how to find it in the binary format files.

Comment: "This is why it is not a good idea to share work-related spreadsheets with other people, unless you first clear out this sort of information" - how would one make sure this info. isn't there, when sharing worksheets?

Comment: @BruceWayne - that would be the same way that the OP did - by using the Document Inspector.  In Excel 2010 that can be found from File / Info /  Check for Issues.  Other versions will have slightly different ways to get to it.

Comment: Ah! Sorry - didn't know that was what that does...I thought it just *checked* for issues, not also helps you remove such info. Thanks!

Comment: @BruceWayne - to be honest, I've never actually used it myself, and I only found out it even existed a couple of months ago - it's not exactly the sort of thing one expects to find, or goes looking for unless someone mentions it exists.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but unfortunately I have an .xls file.

Comment: @WW. - is it 'real' xls file or an xlsx where someone then did a 'save as' as xls ?

Comment: I think it's a real xls. How would I tell?

Comment: @WW the [WorkbookFactory](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/WorkbookFactory.html) parses the file magic and not the extension ... if you receive a HSSFWorkbook its in BIFF8 format otherwise its in OOXML format